# Javascript define class

Tags: javascript, class

What is the best way to define a class? I am aware of the fact that this is most of the times a choice of what you prefer to use, but what is the direct difference between these 3 examples?

Example 1

```
var Class = (function(){
    function Class() {
      this.test = 'test'                
    }
    return Class;
})();

var c = new Class();
console.log(typeof Class);
console.log(c.test);
```

Example 2

```
var Class2 = function(){
      this.test = 'test'                
};

var c2 = new Class2();
console.log(typeof Class2);
console.log(c2.test);
```

Example 3

```
function Class3(){
      this.test = 'test'                
};

var c3 = new Class3();
console.log(typeof Class3);
console.log(c3.test);
```

Sometimes I use it like this as well:
        var Class = (function(){
        var Private = {}, Public = {};

```
    Private._doSomething = function() {
        // something
    }

    Public.doSomethingElse = function() {
        // something else
    }
    return Public;
    })();
```

Comment: Won't help much, but there are actually no classes in ECMAScript/JavaScript; if you make a heavy use of `instanceof`, you probably need to study the language more thoroughly.

Comment: Well the first thing to remember is that there really is no such thing as a "Class" in JavaScript. You can *mimic* that sort of structure in several ways, but the language natively has no such construct. *edit* -- ha ha

Comment: While it's true that JavaScript doesn't have Class (initially capped) features (yet), it's still valid to speak in terms of classes (lower case) of objects -- e.g., objects that share common features. Julien is quite right that a lot of `typeof`, `instanceof`, and such usually means one is missing a trick.

Comment: I agree with you, T.J.; but the issue with the "Class" keyword is that it often implicitly goes along with class inheritance, whereas JavaScript's inheritance is object/instance based.

Comment: you may use this little script: http://classjs.weew.ch/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note:** The main answer below was written in 2012. See the end for additional notes regarding JavaScript's own `class` feature (ES2015+).

---

"Best" is an inherently subjective thing, but I'll try to point out some information about each and let you make up your own mind about "best."

#### Example 1

...gives you a handy scope (the anonymous function) where you can put truly private class-wide information (and utility functions) which only the `Class` functions have access to:

```
var Class = (function(){
    var trulyPrivateInformation = 42;

    function trulyPrivateUtilityFunction() {
        // ...
    }

    function Class() {
      this.test = 'test';
    }
    return Class;
})();
```

Example 1 is not "hoisted." It is processed as part of the step-by-step code.

The `Class` function will have a real name.

#### Example 2

...creates a function <s>that has no name and assigns it to a variable that has a name. Modern browsers are pretty smart about it, but in theory at least, the function is anonymous, which impacts what information your tools can provide you.</s> that (as of ES2015) has a name (`Class2`) except in obsolete environments like IE. It doesn't have the private class-wide scope Example 1 has.

Like Example 1, Example 2 is processed as part of the step-by-step code, not hoisted.

#### Example 3

...is just Example 1 without the private class-wide scope, but it's also "hoisted" — the `Class` function is defined before **any** step-by-step code is executed. That means this works:

```
var c = new Class();
console.log(c.test); // Logs 'test'

function Class() {
    this.test = 'test';
}
```

Note that even though `Class` is defined lower down, it's done *before* the code above runs. This isn't true of either Example 1 or Example 2.

As with Example 1 (but not 2), the `Class` function has a real name.

---

In 2015, JavaScript got its own `class` syntax. Here in 2019, it's natively supported by all modern browsers, and you can transpile with tools like Babel if you need to support IE. Here's how `class` would relate to the OP's question:

#### Example 1 with `class`

```
const Class = (() => {
    let trulyPrivateInformation = 42;

    function trulyPrivateUtilityFunction() {
        // ...
    }

    return class Class {
        constructor() {
            this.test = 'test';
        }
    }
})();
```

Processed in the step-by-step execution of code. Has truly private scope (within the anonymous scoping function) for truly private stuff. Has a proper name.

#### Example 2 with `class` (which is also Example 3 with `class`)

```
class Class2 {
    constructor() {
        this.test = 'test';
    }
}

let c2 = new Class2();
console.log(typeof Class2);
console.log(c2.test);
```

Processed in the step-by-step execution of code. Doesn't have the truly private scope Example 1 has (though private fields and methods are coming soon). Has a proper name.

Comment: And if you're interested in doing this stuff in JavaScript, I've done a toolkit script called [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) to simplify it if you end up doing hierarchies.

Comment: Well thank you TJ!  Yeah, for the others, I am quite aware of the fact that there is no official class-support -yet- in javascript. I hope it will come, but I guess that is still in discussion.  I will def. take a look at your lib!

Comment: +1 some really good points. For me example 3 is 'best' because it is closest to classes in OO languages. What do you mean by truly private for the first example? Example 3 can have private methods and properties if you define them without the `this` keyword and with the `var` keyword respectively.

Comment: Your lib looks quite similar to this one... http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html

Comment: @barry: As well it should, I wrote both. :-) (In fact, see the inset box near the top of that blog post.)

Comment: @MrCode: I'm talking about truly private shared information and utility functions *across instances*. I'm not seeing what Example 3 brings that Example 1 doesn't, and Example 1 has the added advantage of the truly private shared space. :-)

Comment: @barry: Glad that helped! Re class support: Yes, it's [definitely happening](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:classes) in ES.next (e.g., ES6), along with [private properties](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:private_name_objects) and some other cool (and also, to my mind, uncool) stuff.

Comment: @TJ: hehe, nice!  But wich kind do you suggest to use, because in your blogpost from 2009 you do not encourage to use the Helper lib. Are you still having those thoughts or do you encourage the usage of the Helper, or maybe even better: LineAge... ?

Comment: @MrCode despite not being called the same way, and also requiring you to pass in arguments and collect return statements, the `trulyPrivateFunctionality` would be closest to `private static` in other languages. It is data/functionality shared by each instance, which they all have access to through public/private functions (not through `prototype`, though)...  ...but none of the *"static"* methods have references to the instance data, so you must pass in your arguments, and other than directly modifying object/array properties in the static-helper, you must collect the return.

Comment: @barry: That post doesn't say you shouldn't use a helper script, I'm pretty sure it says the opposite. :-) (It does say not to rely on `arguments.callee`, but that's different.) My current recommendation is to use [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as I understand it example 3 can have private methods and properties across instances (not shared instance data). You said yourself that 3 is hoisted, because of this, coupled with the clean and simple syntax I would go with 3. I appreciate there aren't really any functional benefits but I like it because it resembles other OO languages classes and I think e.g. 1 sort of breaks the general definition of a class which is a blueprint and is not a variable and doesn't care where it is defined in respect to flow of execution.

Comment: @MrCode: No, Example 3 as quoted by the OP (and above) has no provision for private methods and properties across instances. (Only *within* an instance, by defining them in the constructor function itself.) I agree the hoisting is nice (some find it evil, I don't), but as what I do is most similar to Example 1, I just make sure to define my "classes" before I try to use them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder by that do you mean share instance data? I agree that Example 3 can't share instance data but I wouldn't want to, for me the instance should be independent of other instances but share the same interface. Norguard thanks for the info, that's a great point about them being more like static.

Comment: @MrCode: It's common for a class to have class-wide data that should be private (to the class), and class-wide utility functions which similarly should be private (to the class). That's what I'm talking about. For instance, you might have a shared table you look up information in. In Example 1, you can do that (`trulyPrivateInformation` is available to all code defined within the scoping function). In Example 3, there's no way to do that. Again, *instances* can have private data, but there's no *common* private data area.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah I agree about the shared area which could be a benefit if you need it. Going back to reflecting other OOP, I think example 3 keeps it inline with the OOP fundamental of encapsulation.

Comment: @MrCode: All three of them can handle encapsulation of *instance* data (in the same way). The advantage of Example 1 over the other two is that it also enables encapsulation of *class* data.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what I mean is 3 is wholly encapsulated and so following OOP fundamentals. I would say it's not very common to need objects to have a shared space that are private to the class but if you do then absolutely example 1 is the way to go.

Comment: @MrCode: We'll have to just agree to disagree, I don't see any encapsulation from Example 3 that Example 1 doesn't have. I do see the converse. Best,